# Como consertar o erro "Unexpected end of archive" quando baixo o arquivo do tipo ByteArrayResource?

Tags: react, typescript, spring-boot

Estou tendo problema ao baixar um arquivo do tipo ByteArrayResource, basicamente, estou utilizando o spring boot como backend, e reactjs no front, quando faço a requisição para o arquivo, o que eu preciso fazer é:

- pegar uma lista de um conjunto de um modelo.
- passar cada entrada dessa para excel.
- compactar esse(s) arquivo(s) excel.
- enviar como ByteArrayResource para o frontend, que por sua vez, vai realizar o download desse arquivo.

Segue a parte do código referente ao backend:

- Controller.

  @PostMapping(value = "export")
  public ResponseEntity getItemsExport(
  // request params
  ) throws IOException {

  ```
        //nome do arquivo zip
        String zipName = "ARQUIVOS.zip";

        // lista com os nomes dos arquivos excel
        List<String> csvNames = eService.createExcel(params);

        eService.compress(csvNames, zipName);

        File file = new File(zipName);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + zipName)
            .contentLength(data.length)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(resource);
  ```

  }
- Service.

public List createExcel(params) {
while (hasNext) {
Page response = repository.getItems(params);
hasNext = response.hasNext();

```
            String fileNameCsv = originalFileNameCsv;
            if (hasNext) {
                fileNameCsv += " part_" + partCount.toString() + ".xls";
                partCount++;
            } else {
                fileNameCsv += ".xls";
            }
            csvNames.add(fileNameCsv);
            try (var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                var outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileNameCsv)) {
                var planilha = workbook.createSheet("Planilha 1");
                int rowNum = 0;

                setHeader(planilha, rowNum++);
                
                for (Modelo item : items) {
                    var linha = planilha.createRow(rowNum++);
                    setCell(linha, 0, item.getVariavel());
                    // outras células
                }
                workbook.write(outputStream);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Erro ao processar o arquivo");
            }
        }

        return csvNames;
}

public void compress(List<String> csvNames, String outputFileName) throws IOException {

        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        for (String csvName : csvNames) {
            File fileToZip = new File(csvName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName());
            zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            fileToZip.delete();
            fis.close();
        }

        zipOut.close();
        fos.close();
    }
```

no front end a requisição é feita da seguinte maneira:

```
public async loadItemsToExport(
        // parametros para busca
    ): Promise<IAxiosResponse<any>> {
        const params = new URLSearchParams()
        // param settings
        return axiosInstance
            .post(`${this.apiVersion}/items/export?${params}`,
            {
                ...filtros,
                responseType: 'blob'
            })
            .then((response: any) => new Blob([response.data]))
            .then((responseBlob: Blob) => saveAs(responseBlob, `ARQUIVOS.zip` ))
    }
```

o problema é que essa requisição, quando é finalizada sempre da o problema descrito no título(Unexpected end of archive) quando abro o arquivo compactado.
[Imagem do problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkcAU.png)

pegar a lista, transformar a lista em um ou mais arquivos excel(dependendo da quantidade de itens) compactar a lista e retornar o arquivo compactado.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

consegui solucionar o problema dividindo em duas requisições, ou seja, uma requisição para criar os arquivos e compactalos, e uma outra para retornar o arquivo em byte[],

no caso o controller ficou assim:

```
@PostMapping(value = "export") public ResponseEntity<String> getItemsExport( // request params ) throws IOException {

      //nome do arquivo zip
      String zipName = "ARQUIVOS.zip";

      // lista com os nomes dos arquivos excel
      List<String> csvNames = eService.createExcel(params);

      eService.compress(csvNames, zipName);

      return ResponseEntity.ok()
          .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + zipName)
          .contentLength(data.length)
          .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
          .body(zipName);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/export")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> exportZipFile(
        @RequestParam("filename") String filename
    ) throws IOException {
        File arquivo = new File(filename);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(arquivo)) {
            StreamUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] bytesDoArquivo = outputStream.toByteArray();
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentLength(bytesDoArquivo.length)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(bytesDoArquivo);
    }
```